# Wordpress PHP - need to retain nextpage paginating tag in custom query

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Preface: i am not a good coder.

I need to use `$post->post_content` to get the raw post so that i can use the EXPLODE php command. But when i do use `$post->post_content`, it filters out the  tags that are in my post which need to be retained. here is my script. what am i doing wrong? thanks!

```
<?php

$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

$contents = array_filter(explode("</p>", $content));

foreach ($contents as $content) {
    if (strpos($content, '<img') !== false ) {
        echo $content;
        echo "</p>after image ad";
    } else {
        echo $content;
        echo "</p>";
    }
}

?>
```

I'm basically trying to insert an Ad after any paragraph that only contains an image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you call:

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

It applies `autop` to split the paragraphs, and also applies `do_shortcode` on all shortcodes.

So you'd better not to call `apply_filters` here, but call `wpautop` instead:

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

```
<?php

$content = wpautop( $post->post_content );

$contents = array_filter(explode("</p>", $content));

$result = '';

foreach ($contents as $content) {
    $result .= $content.'</p>';
    if (strpos($content, '<img') !== false ) {
        $result .= "after image ad";
    }
}

$content = apply_filters('the_content', $result);

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: note that i'm using the <!--nextpage--> shortcode to paginate my posts