# Pagebreak using wp_link_pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php script that reads a text file of 10000 urls one in each line. The script displays all the urls in a blog post. I want the page to be divided into 10 small pages to facilitate comfortabe browsing. So how to add a pagebreak using `<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>` function inside a post? Something like this:

```
<?php
echo "Hi, This is First Page";

wp_link_pages();  

echo "Hi, This is Second Page";
?>
```

Comment: You are already opened php tag in first line you do not need to open again for wp_link_pages(); only use that function simply wp_link_pages() without echo.

Comment: I changed the code using wp_link_pages() and still it doesn't work.

Comment: @ajeshkdy you need break or what is your expected output

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how `wp_link_pages();`  works. It only displays your `the_content` in pages if your `the_content` contains this tag `<!--nextpage-->`

sudo code

```
<?php
echo apply_filter ("the_content" , "Hi, This is First Page<!--nextpage-->Hi, This is second Page");
wp_link_pages(); 
?>
```

You might want to check out this question as to how to retain the page data if you are creating your own page content and not using the standard content area.

[Wordpress PHP - need to retain nextpage paginating tag in custom query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221837/wordpress-php-need-to-retain-nextpage-paginating-tag-in-custom-query)

Answer (score 0):

When already in a php block, you can execute a function without opening another php block. According to the documentation, `wp_link_pages();` should also be called without `echo`.

```
wp_link_pages();
```

Documentation:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages

Comment: But this doesn't work. The output is this: Hi, This is First PageHi, This is Second Page

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```php
global $post;
$total = substr_count($post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->') + 1;
```